# For loop overwriting files instead of continuing with next iteration and creating single separated files

Tags: python, file, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm creating a script that scraps words from the Leo dictionary. I found that the easier and better way to do this is by downloading a pdf file that contains all the necessary info for each word in a table, and then parsing it with the camelot module.

However all the ways I've tried so far always lead to the same problem: The script executes the inner for loop several times instead of continuing with the outer (the next iteration) and therefore it overwrites all the pdfs into the last one it got and letting me with a bunch of pdfs that are all exactly the same.

Here's the code I've wrote:

````
```
#this links list contains all the links from a previous function

for leoWordLink in links:
    driver.get(leoWordLink)
    getTableClass = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "is-clickable"  )
    getTableClass.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='Substantivtabelle öffnen']").click()

    time.sleep(5)

    getPdfTable = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ion-toolbar[@class= 'ion-color ion color-tertiary md in-toolbar hydrated']")
    getPdflink = getPdfTable.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ion-button[@class='ion-color ion-color-primary md button button-clear in-toolbar in-toolbar-color in-buttons ion-activatable ion-focusable hydrated']").get_attribute("href")

    pdflink = "https://dict.leo.org/" + getPdflink
    
    #this is only for me to see where the script is at in a more visible manner in order of trying to debug it
    driver.get(pdflink)
    print ("end  of first for loop")

    for wordVar in WordsDictionary.keys():
        filename = Path(f"WordPDF_{wordVar}" + ".pdf")
        response = requests.get(pdflink)
        print(f"got {pdflink} ")

        os.chdir(cwd + "//pdfsDir")
        filename.write_bytes(response.content)
        print (f"created {wordVar} file")
        print("end of second for loop")
        continue
```
````

This is the output I get:

````
```
(.venv) miguel@miguel-System:~/DEV/PY_AnkiCCreator$ /home/miguel/DEV/PY_AnkiCCreator/.venv/bin/python /home/miguel/DEV/PY_AnkiCCreator/LEO.py

end  of first for loop
got https://dict.leo.org//pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHypCnrUYtNNPMzOsAoG5LNkzuWKW6A6BKWJx96Rk7OgqL0vdZ-HmLsB00i2afRKlLkQdiZ9nttomt0OrZfGxLNUt0h-a32hTREEXlbBSuLoq10-_ZfmwDNkp0Hf3-W_VIUQVldBlAAYoC&lp=esde&lang=de 
created Pilze file
end of second for loop
got https://dict.leo.org//pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHypCnrUYtNNPMzOsAoG5LNkzuWKW6A6BKWJx96Rk7OgqL0vdZ-HmLsB00i2afRKlLkQdiZ9nttomt0OrZfGxLNUt0h-a32hTREEXlbBSuLoq10-_ZfmwDNkp0Hf3-W_VIUQVldBlAAYoC&lp=esde&lang=de 
created Wände file
end of second for loop
got https://dict.leo.org//pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHypCnrUYtNNPMzOsAoG5LNkzuWKW6A6BKWJx96Rk7OgqL0vdZ-HmLsB00i2afRKlLkQdiZ9nttomt0OrZfGxLNUt0h-a32hTREEXlbBSuLoq10-_ZfmwDNkp0Hf3-W_VIUQVldBlAAYoC&lp=esde&lang=de 
created dröhnte file
end of second for loop
end  of first for loop
got https://dict.leo.org//pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHypCmrUButQIZTe1ZZGmUtAhtXjGtDS_JAMRytJS3YIvIH_RfOzmKulS5S7x1QKjJFVzn-AGhLouekzYHavdQtdYuRt6y3i4fUF4lbxnnfdPFSPTRPW8BrxM2XPz32RsQ&lp=esde&lang=de 
created Pilze file
end of second for loop
got https://dict.leo.org//pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHypCmrUButQIZTe1ZZGmUtAhtXjGtDS_JAMRytJS3YIvIH_RfOzmKulS5S7x1QKjJFVzn-AGhLouekzYHavdQtdYuRt6y3i4fUF4lbxnnfdPFSPTRPW8BrxM2XPz32RsQ&lp=esde&lang=de 
created Wände file
end of second for loop
got https://dict.leo.org//pdf/flectionTable.pdf?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHypCmrUButQIZTe1ZZGmUtAhtXjGtDS_JAMRytJS3YIvIH_RfOzmKulS5S7x1QKjJFVzn-AGhLouekzYHavdQtdYuRt6y3i4fUF4lbxnnfdPFSPTRPW8BrxM2XPz32RsQ&lp=esde&lang=de 
created dröhnte file
end of second for loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
```
````

The script ends in failure because the last 'dröhnte' iteration is a verb and the script currently only deals with substantives, so selenium doesn't found its table therefore throws an error. Nonetheless the file is created but contains the same table from the 'Wände' table (the last one before it crashes) and so does the 'Pilze' table (The first one before Wände).

Comment: Nothing to do with your issue but why did you use `f"WordPDF_{wordVar}" + ".pdf"` rather than just `f"WordPDF_{wordVar}.pdf"`? It's like you couldn't *quite* commit to f-strings :-)

Comment: Oh thanks for that! Honestly I just learned about f strings the other day late at night and might have gone over my head that I could just do what you did haha

Comment: In each iteration of the outer for-loop, the inner for-loop iterates through the same `WordsDictionary.keys()` and (over)writes the same files. Appending to the files instead of overwriting them may be a solution.